# Spring Boot Read timed out issue (SocketTimeoutException)

Tags: spring-boot, serversocket, spring-websocket

We have a Spring Boot app that at one point runs a Thread that calls a rest API and does something. When I run it on my machine it works well. Then if I run the same code on another machine it throws the error

```
SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out issue
```

So I thought there was some problem with server timeout. So on the other machine I've tried setting `server.connection-timeout:-1` in the `application.yml`. since I've pulled the code from github, all the settings were identical. Then, after changing this on the other machine, it worked well there too.
So I am curious about the difference could be, maybe some settings on the machine itself? Where can I look?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. Can you confirm that no firewall blocks the request?

Comment: Yes, no firewall problem